# Interp2 function returns faulty interpolated matrix

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a question concerning the interpolation 2 function. I am trying to interpolate some data matrix which is in respect to a cartesian grid. I have to interpolate the data to a polar grid (not with cart2pol). Yet when I create my new grid and use the function interp2 or grid data I only get 1 column of the interpolated matrix and a whole lot of NaN's.
Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
zpoints=1024;
xpoints=512;
zmax=10e-6
w0=0.6e-6;
rmax=10*w0;
z=linspace(-zmax,zmax,zpoints);
r=linspace(0,rmax,xpoints);
[R,Z]=meshgrid(r,z);
I=peaks(R,Z);
pp=surf(R,Z,I)
rmax=1;
rpoints=512;
thetapoints=1024;
asmall=linspace(0,rmax,rpoints);
Theta=linspace(0,2*pi,thetapoints);
[a,TH]=meshgrid(asmall,Theta);
X=a.*cos(TH);
Y=a.*sin(TH);
I2=interp2(R,Z,I,X,Y);
% % figure
% % pp=surf(X,Y,I);
set(pp,'edgecolor','none');
```

This should give an interpolated matrix in the expected good but only returns 1 column as mentioned above.
Can anyone help to see my problem here? 
thanks!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Do you get NaNs in about 75% of the values?

Comment: i only get 1 constant column of numbers and all the other 1024x511 values are NaN

Comment: [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) returns `NaN` when the value to interpolate is outside the specified range.

Comment: `R` has a max value of 6e-6, while `X` has a max value of 1. This throws NaN because you are trying to interpolate with numbers from `X` that do not exist in `R`. This is the same case for `Z`, because the max for `Z` is 1e-5, and the max for `Y` is 1. In order to fix this, you'll have to either change `R` and `Z` to fit `X` and `Y`, or vice-versa.

Comment: @medicine_man thank you this seems to be the problem! but the dimensions of R and Z are predetermined in my real code and i need a range of 0-2pi for my polar conversion? how can i change these limits without changing the desired outcome?

Comment: It seems to me as if you wish to interpolate your `R` and `Z` values as your lookup with 0 to 2pi as your reference. Try `I2=interp2(X,Y,I,R,Z);`

Comment: @medicine_man this is not possible since X and Y are not a valid MESHGRID. The data in I is with respect to the R-Z grid

Comment: Duh. My bad. If `X` and `Y` do not fall within `R` and `Z`, then I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: So its impossible to convert my data to a polar grid? @medicine_man

Comment: Are `R` and `Z` also polar coordinates in your actual data?

Comment: no they are a cartesian grid @medicine_man

Comment: Then you would probably need to make a cartesian grid and convert to polar after you interpolate.